# Uncaught TypeError implementing Fuelux wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I'm trying to implement Fuelux's wizard feature and have hit a brick wall. I am simply trying to achieve a working replica of the [live example](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard) but keep receiving the error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wizard'
```

I am finding a lot of the documentation a little overwhelming and would appreciate some clarity on the subject in plain [or plainer] English.

My markup is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js fuelux">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>E-Learning</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fuelux.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="my-wizard" class="wizard">
            <ul class="steps">
                <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Step 1<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span>Step 2<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span>Step 3<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span>Step 4<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span>Step 5<span class="chevron"></span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="btn btn-mini btn-prev"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wizard.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#my-wizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
                console.log('change');
                if(data.step===3 && data.direction==='next') {
                    // return e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            $('#my-wizard').on('changed', function(e, data) {
                console.log('changed');
            });

            $('#my-wizard').on('finished', function(e, data) {
                console.log('finished');
            });

            $('.btn-prev').on('click', function() {
                console.log('prev');
                $('#my-wizard').wizard('previous');
            });

            $('.btn-next').on('click', function() {
                console.log('next');
                $('#my-wizard').wizard('next','foo');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based off of the title it means you're either not adding the wizard.js file you need or you're trying to make a call to `wizard` before wizard.js has loaded. I guess I'm a little confused because I assume you need to call `.wizard` on the parent element to have it present right? Is that all of your code?

Comment: You include require.js but don't use it?

Comment: @Snuffleupagus: Based on the code he gave us that is not the case. Rather something failed to load or to execute.

Comment: @Bergi if there was an error in the script elsewhere the console would indicate such

Comment: I included require.js based on other examples... Until which I was receiving errors stating that something was undefined.... This is all the code, yes.

Comment: I've bundled this up if anyone wants to see the working files...
[wizard-test.7z](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9wgqg0m34prhkw/wizard-test.7z)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So close!  For both the CSS and JS since Fuel UX includes Bootstrap you simply include Fuel UX in place of Boostrap and you get all of Bootstrap plus Fuel UX:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/css/fuelux.min.css">
<script src="https://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/loader.min.js"></script>
```

Your template looks great and with just the above modifications, plus removing a couple of lines that were causing double-processing, this works just as expected.  See the full example here:

Gist: https://gist.github.com/adamalex/5412079

Live example: http://bl.ocks.org/adamalex/5412079

Comment: @Adam... You, sir, have saved me greatly. I had trouble with your live examples not appearing to loading some of the remote resources but when I redirected the references to local copies it worked a charm. If I can ask you to expand a little on your response... What is loader.min.js for? and why do you not need to include the wizard.js? Thanks again, it helps a lot when trying to understand these things to have a working example... Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, loader.min.js contains all of the JavaScript from Bootstrap and Fuel UX (including wizard and all other controls), plus a minimal AMD loader (Almond) which loads everything up without you needing to provide your own loader like RequireJS.